# Не могу правильно построить гистограммы в Seaborn

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Начал строить гистограммы колонок датафрейма при помощи библиотеки seaborn. Однако, вместо классической гистограммы получил что-то такое[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(17,12))
for i, data in enumerate(df.drop(labels=['School','School_Type'],axis=1).columns):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
    sns.histplot(x=df['School_Type'],y=data,data=df,binwidth=2)
```

Подскажите, как можно решить подобную проблему. Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте `x='School_Type'`

Comment: Пробовал, ничего не меняется

Answer (score 2):

Интересно, что вы хотели получить? "Классическая гистограмма" - это подсчёт числа событий, распределённых по одной шкале. В обычной гистограмме вы не указываете ось `y`, значения по оси вычисляются автоматически.

В вашем случае шкал две:

- во-первых, вы разделяете данные по типам учебного заведения, задав `x=df['School_Type']`
- во-вторых, вы разделяете данные по группам показателей по оси `y`

В результате вы получаете именно то, что должны были получить - диаграмму, в которой число событий кодируется цветом, так как график двумерный.

Единственный вариант "классической гистограммы", который кажется мне разумным в вашей ситуации, это гистограмма с несколькими типами столбцов, вроде такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `seaborn` такой тип гистограммы называется `dodge`. В вашем примере это могло бы быть так:

```
sns.displot(df, x="SAT", hue="School_Type", multiple="dodge")
```

В общем случае в цикле перебирайте имена колонок и подставляйте их в параметр `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Pak Uula, что напомнил про параметр `hue=`. Можно ещё вот так сделать, хотя результаты мне не совсем понятны, но, видимо, серое - это где данные совпадают, а где какого-то типа больше на сколько-то, там цветное. Данные искусственные, поскольку вы своих не предоставили:

```
sns.histplot(hue='School_Type',x=data,data=df,binwidth=2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По идее это "stacked" гистограмма, не знаю, как на русском называется. В ней столбики рисуются один над другим. Только почему-то у вас три набора цветов, а в легенде графика только два.

Comment: @PakUula Ну вот мне кажется, что третьим цветом показываются совпадающие значения, а уже разница показывается цветом конкретного значения. Ну либо я намудрил что-то с искусственными данными.